# Is there a way to speed up the contains extension in a LINQ query for large datasets?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

Thanks for looking.

## Background

I have a C# method that allows a user to pass in a search and filter object.  The method then calls upon a `FULLTEXT` function in SQL via the Entity Framework as an `IQueryable`.  The same `IQueryable` is then further mutated per the constraints of the filter and finally enumerated. This works fine, here is a psuedocode example:

```
var db = MyDataContext();

IQueryable<Foo> results = db.QueryAllMyFoos();

results = db.SomeFullTextFunctionInTheDatabase("buzz");

. . .

return results.Skip(0).Take(10); //etc. etc.
```

## Problem

I have been presented with the requirement that I must save the searches and also enable searching within a result set.

I thought this would be easily solved by storing an array of integers representing the unique ids of a first search, and passing those into the predicate of the second using `.Contains()` (again, pseudocode):

```
var firstSearchResults = int[]{50,63,123. . . .456788};

IQueryable<Foo> results = db.QueryAllMyFoos();

results = db.SomeFullTextFunctionInTheDatabase("fizz").Where(w => firstSearchResults.Contains(w.Id));
```

Well, it *works* but it's unacceptably slow considering that `firstSearchResults` may often contain more than 20,000 unique ids.

## What I have tried

Of course, I tried the `Contains()` logic mentioned above with a cached array of ids from a prior request.

Second I tried to create a data table in SQL to hold the ids of the saved search, each result id in it's own row.  This did nothing to help with the original problem.

Next, I read up on C# `HashSets` and tried converting `firstSearchResults` to a `HashSet` before using it in the `.Contains()` extension.  This did seem to help, but not nearly enough as some of my searches are still taking 4-5 minutes to return results.

I also tried `.Join()` but the compiler complained that I couldn't reconstruct an instance of my object in the return statement.

I looked into `.Intersect` but that would require me to create a new list of intersecting ids between `firstSearchResults` and the `results` IQueryable.  Then, I would have to enumerate the whole thing to get the final list of results.  Since I am paging the result sets, I need to maintain the queryable nature of `results` until it's time to `order`, `skip`, and `take`.

Last, out of desperation, I looked into writing a SQL stored procedure in which I pass a `datatable` of ids as a `READONLY` parameter and then do a join with the results of my Keyword function that runs the Fulltext search.  This might have worked, but SQL isn't my strong suit and I have temporarily stepped away from that pursuit to make this post.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `SomeFullTextFunctionInTheDatabase` returns `IQueryable`? Changing to `HashSet` should have no effect, as for EF `Contains` call is transformed into `IN` within SQL query anyway, so exact implementation of `IEnumerable` doesn't matter here.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek--Thanks for your reply.  Yes, I am sure, because I can call `SomeFullTextFunctionInTheDatabase` and then further mutate it based on other filter criteria without the full enumeration occuring.  Example `results = results.Where(w => w.EndDate > today);`  If I hover over the results at a breakpoint, I have to click to enumerate before I can see the results.  Thanks again.

Comment: The fact that you have to hover and click before you can see the result does not prove anything. If you call `Where` on `List<T>` you'll see the same behavior during debug session.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek--Ok, I see. Thanks.  At any rate, that function behaves the way I would expect it to as an `IQueryable` given the additional parameters that I am running past the `IQueryable` downstream of the function call.  For example, date filters, product type filters, etc.  In any other situation, it is very fast.  But when I try to check it using the `.Contains()` with more than about 1000 ids in the array, it slows down significantly.  Thanks again.

Comment: Running `Contains` as LINQ to Objects query would dramatically decrease performance, because it would enumerate the entire list of ids (1000 elements?) for each item. Fire up SQL profiles, check what's actually being sent to DB, and make all your method calls are transformed into SQL. When that's true, I don't know how to help you.

Comment: Does "Save the searches" requirement mean save the search results? or save the queries?

Comment: @MikeHixson--Thanks for your reply.  In this case, I need to save both the query and the results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.Intersect()` seems to be providing the best results in terms of performance.

Algorithmically speaking:

1. Let your `IQueryable` fully mutate and then select a list of unique ids from it
2. Intersect that list with the ultra-large list of id's that you wish to limit your search to
3. You now have an array of ids that are valid to return with your search.  Factor in paging (`.Skip(n)`, `.Take(n)`) and you can rapidly construct a subset of your return objects.

Here is a pseudo code example:

```
    //current result set
    var resultIds = iQueryableResults.Select(s => s.Id).ToArray(); 

    //intersect with some other array of ints
    var intersection = resultIds.Intersect(priorResults).ToArray(); 

    //Total the results in the intersection
    var resultCount = intersection.Count();

    //Get an upper boundary for your loop.             
    var upperLimit = (resultCount >= ((filter.Skip + filter.Take) - 1))
                                     ? (filter.Skip + filter.Take) - 1
                                     : resultCount;

    var results = new List<MyReturnObject>();

    //Back to the basics
    for (int i = filter.Skip; i < upperLimit; i++)
    {
           var _id = intersection[i];
           results.Add(QueryAllMyObjects().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == _id));
    }

    return results;
```

This isn't elegant or pretty, but it is working much faster than using `.Contains()` in the `where` predicate (about 2-3 seconds when comparing against id arrays of about 20-30k ids).  Hope it helps someone else.